how to pass variable to component and get the variable in the ng-template with the typescript type?
I've created a component called "foo" that accepts a data object and renders it within an ng-template as its own variable.
However, the issue lies in the fact that within the ng-template, the variable is of type any.
What I aim for is to pass a variable (regardless of its type) and retrieve the same variable within the ng-template, but with proper typing for typing-checking and autocomplete.
Please remember that I want to pass any variable (whether it's an observable, string, number, object, or any other type) to the foo component.
Is this achievable in Angular?
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, ContentChild, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="fooTemplate; context: { data }" />
    </div>
  `,
})
export class FooComponent {
  @ContentChild('foo') fooTemplate!: TemplateRef<unknown>;
  @Input() data: any; // <--- type?
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FooComponent],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>

    <foo [data]="person$ | async">
      <ng-template #foo let-person="data">
        {{ person | json}}
      </ng-template>
    </foo>
   
    <foo [data]="[1,2,3,4]">
      <ng-template #foo let-numbers="data">
        {{ numbers | json}}
      </ng-template>
    </foo>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  person$ = of({
    name: 'toto',
    age: 3,
  });
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Here's the link to the code

To enable type checking within ng-template contexts, a custom directive can be created with a special static property ngTemplateContextGuard
interface TypeChecker<TItem extends any> {
  $implicit: TItem;
}

@Directive({
  selector:'ng-template[typeChecker]', 
  standalone:true 
})
export class TemplateTypeChecker<T>{
  @Input('typeChecker') data!:T; // Define an input property named 'typeChecker' which will receive data of type T


  static ngTemplateContextGuard<TContextItem extends any>(
    _: TemplateTypeChecker<TContextItem>, 
    ctx: unknown 
  ): ctx is TypeChecker<TContextItem> { 
    return true; 
  }
}

Then in template you can use typeChecker directive and provide data so that it will infer automatically.
  <foo [data]="person$ | async">
      <ng-template let-person [typeChecker]="person$ | async">
        {{ person | json}}
      </ng-template>
   </foo>

  <foo [data]="[1,2,3,4]">
      <ng-template [typeChecker]="[1,2,3,4]" let-numbers>
        {{ numbers | json}}
      </ng-template>
  </foo>

I have created this answer based on twitter thread
Example

Nice. Thanks. but can we avoid using [typeChecker]=".."? since I'm already using it in two places: [data]=".." and [typeChecker]="...". It would be convenient if we could just write it once if possible

also, inside ng-template there is an error "Object is possibly 'null'" ({{ person.name | json }}). the data is passed to the component and it's not null. right?

I think you can't avoid that using data twice, and regarding the data being null, since by default, it does not have any default data, it is automatically inferred as null

We can use a method to reapply the desired typing using @if and alias syntax, please find below a stackblitz demonstrating this in action!
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, ContentChild, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="fooTemplate; context: { data }" />
    </div>
  `,
})
export class FooComponent {
  @ContentChild('foo') fooTemplate!: TemplateRef<unknown>;
  @Input() data: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FooComponent],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>

    <foo [data]="person$ | async">
      <ng-template #foo let-person="data">
        @if(setTypeForPerson(person); as personTyped) {
          {{ personTyped | json}}
          {{numbersTyped.age1}}
        }
      </ng-template>
    </foo>
   
    <foo [data]="[1,2,3,4]">
      <ng-template #foo let-numbers="data">
        @if(setTypeForNumbers(numbers); as numbersTyped) {
          {{ numbersTyped | json}}
          {{numbersTyped.age}}
        }
      </ng-template>
    </foo>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  person$ = of({
    name: 'toto',
    age: 3,
  });

  setTypeForPerson(item: any): Person {
    return item as Person;
  }

  setTypeForNumbers(item: any): Numbers {
    return item as Numbers;
  }
}

export interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

export interface Numbers {
  name: string;
  age1: number;
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

the probem with this solution is that I have to create a function with each type that I want. is it possible typescript to infer the typing by passing the variable to the input?

@amirc I don't think its possible, seems like an enhancement request for angular (you can raise on their github)! do wait for someone to comment if its possible!
